# SignalR Core throws disposed exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a hub and it's set up like this:

```
public class MainHub : Hub<IMainHub>
{
    private readonly IJobManager jobManager;

    public MainHub(
        IJobManager jobManager)
    {
        this.jobManager = jobManager;

        this.jobManager.JobUpdated += async (s, e) =>
        {
            await Clients.Group(e.Group).JobUpdate(e.Job);
        };
    }
]
```

The `IJobManager` is a class that use `SqlDependency` to monitor changes on a table and is registered as a singleton. The hub works fine when not subscribed to the `JobUpdated` event (or the event is not fired).

But when the event is fired, I get the following exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MainHub'.

Why does this error occur?

And if I swap the DI in that I inject the hub into the job manager (as this class is a singleton), I assume that the hub will not be disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you are not deregistering the event listener when the `MainHub` has done it's work. You have no control over how long one instance of that one lives...

Don't use an anonymous function and deregister the event listener.

```
public class MainHub : Hub<IMainHub>
{
    private readonly IJobManager jobManager;

    public MainHub(
        IJobManager jobManager)
    {
        this.jobManager = jobManager;

        this.jobManager.JobUpdated += OnJobUpdated;
    }

    private async void OnJobUpdated(object s, Event e)
    {
       await Clients.Group(e.Group).JobUpdate(e.Job);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
          this.jobManager.JobUpdated -= OnJobUpdated;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

You will need to fix the signature of the function there, since I don't know the real one.

Comment: Works fine now!!